# Facebook pulling in data fine; track art still default on Soundcloud

Tags: facebook, caching, default, soundcloud, artwork

I used to be a senior tech (service side) and have just a little (current) programming knowledge, so please forgive me if I missed something obvious about the issue. Here goes: 
I uploaded my second mix to Soundcloud yesterday, and added the artwork in while in was still on the loading/encoding screen. The upload went smoothly and I filled in all the data for the track, and the artwork had loaded properly here:
http://soundcloud.com/dvjrickkraft/rick-kraft-01-2013-electro

I tried sharing to Facebook after that, but I was getting the default Soundcloud JPG. As per your suggestion and previous experience, I ran the link through the Facebook debug (lint) bar, which showed me the page scrape still shows the Soundcloud default when doing a page scrape. I had a similar issue with Mixcloud before when Facebook cached an image before I had set the correct one, ran debug/lint and saw the fresh scrape with all correct information, and it began pulling in the right data.

I also tried variations ?1 ?123 ?2 through the debug (hadn't tried them previously so they wouldn't have been cached) with each pulling the default Soundcloud JPG and not my art.

In addition... the same day I uploaded a previous track here
http://soundcloud.com/dvjrickkraft/rick-kraft-12-05-05
which seems to have been replaced by my shared Jump Smokers track. I didn't delete it, and am at a loss for words as to how it disappeared...!! I wanted to test to see if Facebook pulls in the art for the first upload, but I'll have to reupload at the end of this current promo period. I realize this is likely a separate issue to report.

Any help you can suggest that I can do or your Dev team can do to resolve this would be greatly appreciated. I'm right on the edge of my big breakthrough here as an artist in Taiwan and every lit bit really really counts. Sincerely, Rick Kraft

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this.

It doesn't seem as if the upload of artwork has succeeded. You can see in API response that `artwork-url` has `nil=true` and no actual content – `http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/71930639?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID`

My suggestion would be to re-upload the artwork again and then do the facebook lint trick you were doing.

As for the second issue, maybe [this link](http://help.soundcloud.com/customer/portal/articles/247765-why-did-my-sound-disappear-) will help.

Comment: Thanks for the link + extra info... it'll certainly help me diagnosing any further issues I may have. Very helpful!